# How to focus on input element when click on div class a href button

Tags: javascript, html, input, focus, element

```
 <ul id="top_menu">
  <li>
    <a href="#" id="arabutton" class="search-overlay-menu-btn" ><?php echo $pages->get('/')->text36;?></a>
    </li>
</ul>



        <!-- Search Menu -->
        <div class="search-overlay-menu">

                    <form  id="form-game_v2" name="form-game_v2" method="get" action="<?php $pages->get("template=home")->url ?>" >
                        <div class="typeahead__container">
                            <div class="typeahead__field">
                                <div class="typeahead__query">
                                    <input  class="js-typeahead-game_v2" id="ara" name="form" type="search" placeholder="Search"  autofocus>
                                </div>
                                <div class="typeahead__button">
                                    <button type="submit">
                                        <i class="typeahead__search-icon"></i>
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
        </div><!-- End Search Menu -->
```

i need a focus on input id="ara"
when click on id="arabutton"

How can i do that? its a live search system. when click on button overlay input field appear for type .

live example: http://medilocation.com/en/treatments/pediatric-cardiology/
click on right up corner for search and you see that focus problem.

Comment: Are you using a framework such as Angular, React or Vue? Or are you using something like JQuery? Or are you looking for a plain javascript solution? This will be good information to add to your question if you want a helpfull response.

Comment: i dont use frame work. but i am using jquery-typeahead script for live search system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally did it

```
<script>
 document.getElementById("arabutton").addEventListener("click", function(){
     setTimeout(function() { jQuery('#ara').focus() }, 20);
});
</script>
```

arabutton is id of the button. when click on it overlay form comes.
ara is id of inputfield on the overlay form

Answer (score 2):

You should use JavaScript:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const input = document.getElementById('ara');
  const button = document.getElementById('arabutton');

  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    input.focus();
  })
})
```

Comment: overlay form appear when click on button. I think we should make when form load focus on inputfield.

Answer (score 0):

```
const btn = document.querySelector('#arabutton');
const input = document.querySelector('#ara'); // or getElementById

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
   input.focus();
});
```

Captain Obvious?

Answer (score 0):

use javascript events

```
<script>
  function focus(event) {
      e.preventDefault() //to stop the redirection effect
      document.getElementById("ara").focus()
  }
 </script>
 <a onclick="focus()" id="arabutton" class="search-overlay-menu-btn">page</a>
 <input class="js-typeahead-game_v2" id="ara" name="form" type="search" placeholder="Search" autofocus>
```